# How to reload Table view after inserting object in core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm trying to insert some objects in Core Data by this code

```
- (void)insertNewObject: (NSArray *) userInfo // Заносит блюдо в локальную базу данных
{
   for (int i = 0; i < userInfo.count; i++) {
       billContent * bc = [userInfo objectAtIndex:i];
       NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
       NSEntityDescription *entity = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchRequest] entity];
       NSManagedObject *nmo = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name]
                                                                      inManagedObjectContext:context];
       [nmo setValue:CountID forKey:@"billId"];
       [nmo setValue:bc.billAmount forKey:@"courseCount"];
       [nmo setValue:bc.billCourseId forKey:@"courseId"];
       [nmo setValue:bc.billPrice forKey:@"coursePrice"];
       [nmo setValue:bc.billTitle forKey:@"courseTitle"];
       [self saveContext];
   }
}

- (void)saveContext {
   NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
   NSError *error = nil;
   if (![context save:&error]) {
       NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
       abort();
   }
}
```

How to see this objects in my table view?

I'm trying to fetch from core data agin, after inserting, by this code

```
[self makeAList];
```

And here

```
-(void) makeAList {
id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:0];
for (int i = 0; i < [sectionInfo numberOfObjects]; i ++) {
    NSIndexPath *ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: i inSection:0];
    billContent *bc = [[billContent alloc] init];
    NSManagedObject *mo = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:ip];
    bc.billId = [[mo valueForKey:@"billId"] description];
    bc.billTitle = [[mo valueForKey:@"courseTitle"] description];
    bc.billPrice = [[mo valueForKey:@"coursePrice"] description];
    bc.billAmount = [[mo valueForKey:@"courseCount"] description];
    bc.depId = [[mo valueForKey:@"departmentId"] description];
    bc.billCourseId = [mo valueForKey:@"courseId"];
    [saved addObject:bc];
}
[countView1 reloadData];
```

}

But nothing works. But if I out of this class, and enter it again (load viewDidLoad) I can see new values, What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are some standard methods in fetchedResultController that you should override.
Look at the code below:-

```
 -(void) controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}

-(void) controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}

-(void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

switch (type) {
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate: {
        Course *changedCourse = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.textLabel.text = ...;
    }
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;
}
```

}

```
-(void) controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {
switch (type) {
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
        [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
        [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;
}
```

}

Comment: I have such error
error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (6) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (6), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out). with userInfo (null)